# Inaccurate distance from geosearch using bounding circle

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have been trying different methods to speed up the location search on a website, I have been taking instructions from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html.

The code has been tailored to my tables and have input the variables so I can run it through phpmyadmin

```
Select id, outcode, lat, lng, acos(sin(57.101)*sin(radians(lat)) + 
cos(57.101)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-'-2.27')) * 3959 As D
From 
  (Select id, outcode, lat, lng
   From car_postcodes
    WHERE
    lat Between 52.7593142577 And 61.4426857423
    And 
    lng Between -10.2633856968 And 5.72338569684
    ) As FirstCut 
Where acos(sin(57.101)*sin(radians(lat)) + 
cos(57.101)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-'-2.27)) * 3959 < 7000
Order by D
```

The problem is that the search results are displaying the minimum distance 5448 (miles?) away from the location, which isn't correct as all postcodes are within the UK. (hence the '< 7000)

This is the code for finding the min / max longitude & latitude:

```
$lat = 57.101;  // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
$lon = -2.27;  // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
$rad = 300;  // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

$R = 3959;  // earth's mean radius, m

// first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
$maxLat = $lat + rad2deg($rad/$R);
$minLat = $lat - rad2deg($rad/$R);
// compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
$maxLon = $lon + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));
$minLon = $lon - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));
```

The top three results are showing:

```
 ID     postcode      lat      lng      D      
 1143   HS2           58.249   -6.468   5428.525603021315 
 1142   HS1           58.213   -6.381   5432.53243648885
 1144   HS3           57.879   -6.853   5435.933627885293
```

lng & lat columns in the table are stored as binary and are indexed.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have time to help you with this, but I suspect there's a units problem between degrees and radians.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this though with `:start_lat`, `:start_lng`, `:min_distance`, and `:max_distance`, d is in miles. I haven't had a speed problem with it in my code but let me know how it runs.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                *
                FROM (SELECT id, outcode, lat, lng, ( 3959*(2*ASIN(SQRT(POW(SIN(((car_postcodes.lat-:start_lat)*(PI()/180))/2),2)+COS(car_postcodes.lat*0.017453293)*COS(:start_lat*0.017453293)*POW(SIN(((car_postcodes.lng-:start_lgn)*(PI()/180))/2),2)))) ) AS d
                    FROM car_postcodes
                WHERE 1) AS tmp_tbl
            WHERE d <= :max_distance AND d >= :min_distance
            ORDER BY d ASC
```

Comment: It runs but I am having a similar issue as I do with the previous code. Using an example postcode of AB14, between 0 and 200 miles radius and the nearest (the only) post codes that show up are Northern Ireland.

Comment: I have checked a few other postcodes and it seems to be around 200 miles off. Testing CV3, that shows up the results from somewhere is the Isle of Scilly. So at least its consistent